# bertmoticon.infer() sentence of Bertmoticon package not work

Tags: python

I have executed the following:

- `pip3 install bertmoticon`
- `import bertmoticon`
- `print(bertmoticon.infer(ls_of_strings, 3))`

And I obtained the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-e7c02d1c5fb8> in <module>()
----> 1 print(bertmoticon.infer(ls_of_strings,3))

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/bertmoticon/__init__.py in forward(self, x)
    136             input_ids, attention_mask = x
    137             last_layer,embedding = self.bert(input_ids)
--> 138             embedding = torch.mean(last_layer,dim=1)
    139             out = self.fc_class(embedding)
    140             return out, None

TypeError: mean() received an invalid combination of arguments - got (str, dim=int), but expected one of:
 * (Tensor input, *, torch.dtype dtype)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of names dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
 * (Tensor input, tuple of ints dim, bool keepdim, *, torch.dtype dtype, Tensor out)
 * List item
 * List item
```